# adding custom record in PDF in netsuites

Tags: netsuite

The template cannot be printed due to the following errors: Error on line 152, column 25 in template. Detail... The following has evaluated to null or missing: ==> v.custrecordserial_number_record [in template "template" at line 152, column 27] ---- Tip: It's the step after the last dot that caused this error, not those before it. ---- Tip: If the failing expression is known to be legally refer to something that's sometimes null or missing, either specify a default value like myOptionalVar!myDefault, or use <#if myOptionalVar??>when-present<#else>when-missing</#if>. (These only cover the last step of the expression; to cover the whole expression, use parenthesis: (myOptionalVar.foo)!myDefault, (myOptionalVar.foo)?? ---- ---- FTL stack trace ("~" means nesting-related): - Failed at: ${v.custrecordserial_number_record} [in template "template" at line 152, column 25] ---- Error on line 152, column 25 in template. Detail... The following has evaluated to null or missing: ==> v.custrecordserial_number_record [in template "template" at line 152, column 27] ---- Tip: It's the step after the last dot that caused this error, not those before it. ---- Tip: If the failing expression is known to be legally refer to something that's sometimes null or missing, either specify a default value like myOptionalVar!myDefault, or use <#if myOptionalVar??>when-present<#else>when-missing</#if>. (These only cover the last step of the expression; to cover the whole expression, use parenthesis: (myOptionalVar.foo)!myDefault, (myOptionalVar.foo)?? ---- ---- FTL stack trace ("~" means nesting-related): - Failed at: ${v.custrecordserial_number_record} [in template "template" at line 152, column 25] ---- Error on line 152, column 25 in template. Detail... The following has evaluated to null or missing: ==> v.custrecordserial_number_record [in template "template" at line 152, column 27] ---- Tip: It's the step after the last dot that caused this error, not those before it. ---- Tip: If the failing expression is known to be legally refer to something that's sometimes null or missing, either specify a default value like myOptionalVar!myDefault, or use <#if myOptionalVar??>when-present<#else>when-missing</#if>. (These only cover the last step of the expression; to cover the whole expression, use parenthesis: (myOptionalVar.foo)!myDefault, (myOptionalVar.foo)?? ---- ---- FTL stack trace ("~" means nesting-related): - Failed at: ${v.custrecordserial_number_record} [in template "template" at line 152, column 25] ---- Error on line 152, column 25 in template. Detail... The following has evaluated to null or missing: ==> v.custrecordserial_number_record [in template "template" at line 152, column 27] ---- Tip: It's the step after the last dot that caused this error, not those before it. ---- Tip: If the failing expression is known to be legally refer to something that's sometimes null or missing, either specify a default value like myOptionalVar!myDefault, or use <#if myOptionalVar??>when-present<#else>when-missing</#if>. (These only cover the last step of the expression; to cover the whole expression, use parenthesis: (myOptionalVar.foo)!myDefault, (myOptionalVar.foo)?? ---- ---- FTL stack trace ("~" means nesting-related): - Failed at: ${v.custrecordserial_number_record} [in template "template" at line 152, column 25] ---- Error on line 152, column 25 in template. Detail... The following has evaluated to null or missing: ==> v.custrecordserial_number_record [in template "template" at line 152, column 27] ---- Tip: It's the step after the last dot that caused this error, not those before it. ---- Tip: If the failing expression is known to be legally refer to something that's sometimes null or missing, either specify a default value like myOptionalVar!myDefault, or use <#if myOptionalVar??>when-present<#else>when-missing</#if>. (These only cover the last step of the expression; to cover the whole expression, use parenthesis: (myOptionalVar.foo)!myDefault, (myOptionalVar.foo)?? ---- ---- FTL stack trace ("~" means nesting-related): - Failed at: ${v.custrecordserial_number_record} [in template "template" at line 152, column 25] ---- Error on line 152, column 25 in template. Detail... The following has evaluated to null or missing: ==> v.custrecordserial_number_record [in template "template" at line 152, column 27] ---- Tip: It's the step after the last dot that caused this error, not those before it. ---- Tip: If the failing expression is known to be legally refer to something that's sometimes null or missing, either specify a default value like myOptionalVar!myDefault, or use <#if myOptionalVar??>when-present<#else>when-missing</#if>. (These only cover the last step of the expression; to cover the whole expression, use parenthesis: (myOptionalVar.foo)!myDefault, (myOptionalVar.foo)?? ---- ---- FTL stack trace ("~" means nesting-related): - Failed at: ${v.custrecordserial_number_record} [in template "template" at line 152, column 25] ---- Error on line 152, column 25 in template. Detail... The following has evaluated to null or missing: ==> v.custrecordserial_number_record [in template "template" at line 152, column 27] ---- Tip: It's the step after the last dot that caused this error, not those before it. ---- Tip: If the failing expression is known to be legally refer to something that's sometimes null or missing, either specify a default value like myOptionalVar!myDefault, or use <#if myOptionalVar??>when-present<#else>when-missing</#if>. (These only cover the last step of the expression; to cover the whole expression, use parenthesis: (myOptionalVar.foo)!myDefault, (myOptionalVar.foo)?? ---- ---- FTL stack trace ("~" means nesting-related): - Failed at: ${v.custrecordserial_number_record} [in template "template" at line 152, column 25] ---- Error on line 152, column 25 in template. Detail... The following has evaluated to null or missing: ==> v.custrecordserial_number_record [in template "template" at line 152, column 27] ---- Tip: It's the step after the last dot that caused this error, not those before it. ---- Tip: If the failing expression is known to be legally refer to something that's sometimes null or missing, either specify a default value like myOptionalVar!myDefault, or use <#if myOptionalVar??>when-present<#else>when-missing</#if>. (These only cover the last step of the expression; to cover the whole expression, use parenthesis: (myOptionalVar.foo)!myDefault, (myOptionalVar.foo)?? ---- ---- FTL stack trace ("~" means nesting-related): - Failed at: ${v.custrecordserial_number_record} [in template "template" at line 152, column 25

Iam gettting this error while clicking priny button can any one suggest right answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message is saying that your variable `v.custrecordserial_number_record` is empty, or not defined.  That is, the template cannot work with the data you are asking it to work with, because it's not there.  You simplest way to get past this error would be to check it with the `!` operator within the interpolation:

Change

```
${v.custrecordserial_number_record}
```

to

```
${(v.custrecordserial_number_record)!}
```

If you want to show a message when this variable is empty you can add a default value:

```
${(v.custrecordserial_number_record)!"Serial number not available"}
```

All this (and more) is given in the error you posted, so here's another pro-tip: whenever you get an error, read it and try to understand what it's telling you! :)

If `v.custrecordserial_number_record` is a value that should always be present, you need to check how this data is being sent to the template and make sure you're referencing it properly.  (What is `v`, and what is the `custrecordserial_number_record` property of `v`?)

Comment: thank you it is working now but it is showing all the data